# How to use ngFor for 4 elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

Now I use :

```js
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
```

to bring out all elements.
But I need to bring out 4div elements.
Like this:

```js
<div>
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
</div>
```

How could I do that with ngFor?
I have a slider, and I need to show 4 elements at start.

Comment: What is `app`?  Are you asking how to assign `[item]` to `item` for all items? If so then *ngFor needs to go in the `div` tag you have already

Comment: now i have :
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app>
and it show all my [item]
I need use ngFor for bling out 4 div- elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SlicePipe`:

```
<app ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:4" [item]="item"></app>
```

First argument is `start`, second argument is `end`.

Read more about `SlicePipe` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

Comment: what are you mean "first" and "second"?

Comment: @WatchAllMovie `slice:0:4` - 0 and 4 are two arguments that are passed to `SlicePipe`, this is Angular's syntax for passing arguments to pipes.

Comment: and i will have only 4 elems, yes?
Becouse i have a slider, and i need to show 4 elems at start

Comment: @WatchAllMovie Yes, this will get first four elements only.

Comment: okay, thanks)
And i still could scroll for the next elements?